# JavaScript: What is the logic behind the 'shift' method?

Tags: javascript, arrays, shift

Basically, how do you return AND remove the first element of an array WITHOUT using the shift() OR splice() methods(or any other methods for that matter)?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What is the logic behind the 'shift' method?

It's fully described [in the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.9).

> Basically, how do you return AND remove the first element of an array WITHOUT using the shift() OR splice() methods(or **any other methods for that matter**)?

I can't see any good reason for such a restriction, but you can use a loop to manually assign each entry the value of the one above it (starting at the end) until the index you want to change, and then set the `length` of the array to one less. Something vaguely like this (I'm sure this is not a complete implementation of what `shift` does):

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/imahomi/1) | [Live source](http://jsbin.com/imahomi/1/edit)

```
var n;
for (n = theArray.length - 2; n >= removeAt; --n) {
    theArray[n] = theArray[n+1];
}
--theArray.length;
```

Altering the `length` property of an array will remove any elements that no longer fall within the length.

You can also remove an element without altering the length of the array, using `delete`:

```
delete theArray[removeAt];
```

The array's length will be unchanged, but it will no longer have an entry (at all) at that location. It becomes *sparse* (if it wasn't already). This works because the `delete` statement removes properties from objects, and [untyped JavaScript arrays are really just objects](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html).

Comment: You could manually move every element one position to the left as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for. It sets the first letter, then adds-on the rest of the string, replaces the first letter in the finalString variable with an empty string and then returns the first letter saved in the firstLetter variable.

```
function remove(str){
  let firstLetter = '';
  let finalString = '';
  for(let i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
    if(i === 0){
      firstLetter = str[i];
    }
    finalString += str[i];
    if(i === 0){
      finalString = '';
    }
  }
  return firstLetter;
}

remove('hello');
```